# How can I get the insert code to insert as many IDs as necessary?

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2005

When a user completes a form, s/he can complete up to 5 records at a time.

If the the user completes 1 record, the ID increments by 1.

However, when a user completes more than 1 record, we would expect the ID to increment by as many records as the user completed.

For instance, let's say user with ID 2516 completes 3 records, we would expect to see something like:

```
ID    User
1      2516
2      2516
3      2516
```

If another user by id of 4874 completes 2, we would be:

```
ID    User           
 4    4874
 5    4874
```

etc

In stead, the value of ID is incrementing by only 1 no matter how many new records one particular user enters.

I know this is based on the code below.

Can you please help me fix it in such that the value increments based on how many records a particular user submits.

We don't want to use identity seed to increment it.

Your help, as usual, is highly appreciated.

```
sql += "INSERT INTO Emp (UserSequence, employee_id, charity_code, check_amt, chcknum, one_time, bi_weekly, cash, donate_choice, date_stamp) "
                sql += "VALUES ((select isNull(max(UserSequence), 0) + 1, '" & Replace(employee_idLabel.Text, "'", "''") & "','" & Replace(dedval.SelectedValue, "'", "''") & "','" & Replace(chckval.Text, "'", "''") & "','" & Replace(chcknumval.Text, "'", "''") & "','" & Replace(onetimeval.Text, "'", "''") & "','" & multival.Text & "','" & Replace(cashval, "'", "''") & "','" & Replace(donatechoice.SelectedItem.Value, "'", "''") & "','" & Replace(datestamp, "'", "''") & "');"
```

Comment: Are stored procedures out of the question for any reason?  It seems the values (besides the ID) are going to be the same for each inserted record.  It would be more efficient to pass into a proc the amount of records to insert as one param, and all the other values as their own params.

Comment: Do not create values for identity (id) columns by selecting the current MAX(ID) but let the database handle this by IDENTITY. Do not create insert statements by concatenating unchecked user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well this is rather your business logic.
I would recommend you the followin structure

```
create table myTable (
    int UserId not null,
    int myTableId int identity(1,1) primary key,
    int UserSequence int not null
)
```

and do insert statements like this.

```
insert into myTable (UserId, UserSequence) values 
(10, (select isNull(max(UserSequence), 0) + 1 from myTable where UserId=10))
```

It does exactly what you need. You leave your primary key as is but add another column that serves for your business logic.

**EDIT**

By the way, your VB.Code looks very cumbersome.

1. Dont use string concatinations. It is unsafe. (Best case exception about wrong sql, worst case sql injection)
2. Just take a look at some ORM. That will greatly handle a lot of sql burden for you. Personally I suggest you Entity Framework.

With ORM your code would look something like this.

```
Dim dc As New MyDatabaseContext
Dim records = dc.Recors.Where(Function(x) x.UserId = 10)
Dim last as Integer = 0
If records.Count > 0 Then last = records.Max(Function(x) x.UserSequence)
Dim instance As New Record With {
    .UserId = 10,
    .UserSequence = last + 1
}
dc.Records.Add(instance)
dc.SaveChanges()
```

Comment: The decision to use a ORM should not be taken lightly. For many use cases just using parameterized queries will be sufficient.

Comment: @Meta-Knight Why not? If you have small project, it drastically increases the development with no performance drop, if project is big, generating all this sql and parameters will eat you up. (Own experience. I personally wrote about 200 stored procedures in T'SQL) Just take advantage of the *New technologies* and leave plain SQL for a very specific cases.

Comment: I'm just pointing out that using an ORM is not magical, you have to learn how to use it properly, and you might have performance or mapping problems for some queries requiring you to use some hand-coded SQL anyway. So it has its pros and cons. That's my opinion from working with NHibernate for a small-scale project, but your experience with a different project/ORM might differ ;-)

Comment: If I may weigh in this ORM discussion, it looks pretty cool but I am completely lost as to what it is doing and how to apply to my code. I would like to add that my code is more stuff than just the insert i showed.

Comment: @ChidiOkeh Just take some time and learn the EF. [material1](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx), [material2](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application). I promise, this will not be the waste of time.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at making the ID column an [IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) column. This will automatically assign each row an incrementing id, and you don't have to worry about it yourself (i.e. you don't even need to specify the column in the insert statement).

e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE Example
(
ID INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1),
employee_id INTEGER
)

INSERT Example (employee_id) VALUES (2516) -- Gets ID=1
INSERT Example (employee_id) VALUES (2516) -- Gets ID=2
```

Trying to maintain incrementing IDs yourself is likely to end in a world of pain, especially when multiple users try inserting at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response AdaTheDev. I did already say we do not want to make it an identity column. The reason is that we have created what we call Recycle Bin. This means that when data is deleted, it goes into this RecycleBin table. The user can then restore the data if they feel the data was deleted incorrectly. The only way we have been able to make this work is by NOT making the ID on Emp table an identity Column.

Comment: @ChidiOkeh The source of your problem is that you are violating the database design principle that an identity or key shall not have a (business) meaning. Oybek probably provides the best solution to refactor your design.

Comment: @ChidiOkeh - apologies, I failed to read that. However, I'd suggest still using an IDENTITY column, but instead of moving to a RecycleBin table when "deleting", just have a "status" flag which you can set to indicate a record is deleted. This way, to undelete it is just a case of reversing the flag.

Answer (score 0):

this code is not safe, what if another process executes between your SELECT and the INSERT? you could do that in the same shot with SQL:

```
INSERT INTO table EMP (ID, ...) VALUES ( (SELECT MAX(ID)+1 FROM EMP), ...);
```

of course if you can use an autoincrement/sequence field you don't have to worry about ids.

Comment: Oybek, I will try your suggestion. It seems logical enough. I will let you guys know shortly. vulkanino, when you say, not safe, are you referring to Oybek's code or mine?

Comment: yours. you're SELECTing - computing - INSERTing, but while you're computing some other user may invalidate your MAX(ID) selection.

Comment: Thanks everyone for all your fantastic feedbacks. I am getting the following error: Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed with Oybek's code. I have updated my code above with the one I am having issues with right now.

Comment: you shouldn't have updated the question, this way it can't be useful to others!

Comment: sorry, I did it for 2 reasons. First, in the past, I always been asked to update the original code so users can still see it. Second, I tried pasting here but I was told I had gone over character limit.